# Why are colors changed in the preview for my clip on YouTube?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, png

I have 1000 PNGs created with R and ggplot2. This is one for example: [image000.png](http://joyofdata.de/stub/image000.png)

Now I use ffmpeg to glue them together into a clip:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -i image%03d.png -s 1380x720 -vcodec png 
       -qscale 10 -r 30 daimler_man.mov
```

- input frame rate 10 and output frame rate 30 which leads to 10
  different images per second with a video frame rate of 30.
- the images are originally sized 1380 x 720.
- vcodec png ... well it works at least. when I used h264 the video looked nice on my computer but youtube turned the whole clip gray.
- qscale 10 ... I am not sure if this one is optimally chosen.

Everything is fine more or less but when I take the embed code of the [youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsqObW7lc7I) then the displayed preview image looks like this:

[image]

The background color of plot area is now gray instead of light brown!?

**the ffmpeg output**:

```
C:\Users\Raffael\Documents\proj>ffmpeg -r 10 -i image%03d.png -s 1380x720 -vcodec png -qscale 10 -r 30 daimler_man.mov
ffmpeg version N-48785-g2ea3f37 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 12 2013 20:45:33 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu
tls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-l
ibopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwol
ame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
--enable-filter=frei0r
  libavutil      52. 14.100 / 52. 14.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.107 / 54. 59.107
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from 'image%03d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:02.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1380x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
File 'daimler_man.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mov, to 'daimler_man.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.59.107
    Stream #0:0: Video: png (png  / 0x20676E70), rgb24, 1380x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> png)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  151 fps= 26 q=0.0 Lsize=   13037kB time=00:00:05.03 bitrate=21218.1kbits/s dup=100 drop=0
video:13035kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.010533%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YouTube has very specific encoding requirements](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1722171&rd=1). I wouldn't be surprised if it couldn't handle a stream of PNG images in a MOV container, when it actually expects H.264 video (ideally in MP4).

Since YouTube re-encodes whatever you upload to it, it will apply some filters to your video to make it fit. The PNGs come as [non-subsampled 4:4:4 images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:4:4_R.27G.27B.27_.28no_subsampling.29), with an RGB 24-bit color space. H.264 video is usually encoded in a different color space, namely [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV).

YouTube might have simply applied the wrong conversion there when going from RGB to YUV, which is why your light brown (it's actually light grey; check your monitor calibration) background into dark grey.